# Customize output directory for lazy loaded chunks in Angular 4

Tags: angular, webpack

Is there a way to customize the output directory where some of the lazy loaded chunks will be stored? By default, all artifacts go to `dist` folder. But I need to store some of them in a sub-directory of `dist` (these are the chunks for modules that will be customized, and the client wants to keep them separate).

**Example**:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I'm very new to Angular, and it seems that the only way to customize the build output is by doing `ng eject`, and taking the full control over the build configuration, which doesn't seem ideal. But even then, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Care to comment on negative and close vote?

Comment: I have updated my comment after somebody complained. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Check out NRWL's NX to see how to build an enterprise angular application with separation in apps and libs. Your client probably wants the code related to him to be in a lib rather than the app itself. For the lib you can define an own tsconfig, which is extending the main project's tsconfig. Here is an example: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples/blob/master/libs/login/tsconfig.lib.json

Pay attention to the line

```
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/libs/login",
```

which specifies where the output will be built.

Comment: This is not enough information. How should he edit it?

Comment: @Glitcher I have updated my answer. Hope this makes it more clear

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 7+, you could use [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack).

Here's how to use it for Angular 12:

1. Install [@angular-builder/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack):

   ```sh
   npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack
   ```
2. Update `angular.json` to use custom webpack file:

   ```json
   "projects": {
     ...
     "example-app": {
       ...
       "architect": {
         ...
         "build": {
           "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
           "options": {
             "customWebpackConfig": {
                 "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create "extra-webpack.config.js" in project root directory. Update the case values as needed for your files. This is a modified example from the [webpack Output documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkfilename)

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     output: {
       chunkFilename: (pathData) => {
         let fileName;

         switch (pathData.chunk.id) {
           case 1:
             fileName = 'custom_dir/[name].js';
             break;
           case 3:
             fileName = 'custom_dir/[name].js';
             break;
           default:
             fileName = '[name].js';
         }

         return fileName;
       }
     }
   };
   ```
4. Run `ng build` to generate dist folder with sub-directories.

Comment: Where do I get the chunk-ids?

Comment: You can inspect the build files to see the chunk ids. Alternatively, you can you use the "--named-chunks" options with "ng build" which will use the file name for the chunk file name. You will also have to update the switch statement to use the "name" instead of "id".

Comment: I managed to achieve the solution by just adding another parameter to the lazyLoad-Resolve

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the solution by just adding another parameter to the lazyLoad-Resolve cause I was having a similar problem:

```
lazyLoad: ['$q', '$transition$', function($q, $transition$) {
                const deferred = $q.defer();
                const $ocLazyLoad = $transition$.injector().get("$ocLazyLoad");

                // Async require => Split point
                require.ensure([], () => {
                    //
                    // All the code here, plus the required modules
                    // will be bundled in a separate file.
                    let module = require('../secure/app.secure.module.ajs');
                    //
                    // OCLazyLoad's 'load' function loads the Angular module.
                    $ocLazyLoad.load({name: 'collphir.customer-secure'});

                    deferred.resolve(module);
                }, 'secure/secure');

                return deferred.promise;
            }]
```

The line

```
}**, 'secure/secure'**);
```

is the solution. Took me a while to find this one on the internet... No need for the **extra-webpack.config.js**. Also, there is a weird thing with the solution suggestion by **@Cofad**: Only the lazy chunk runs through this switch-case, so actually it is not necessary to differentiate. Also, I can't use the lazy-chunk's **[name]** cause it doesn't have one so I tried it with the **[id]**, but this does change when building in prod-mode. So I tried it with the **[debugId]** which seemed to stay the same. It felt very unstable to me though...